# Mock RouteData in RhinoMocks-MVC3

Tags: rhino-mocks

How to Mock RouteData in RhinoMock?

I have to Mock this.

`(RouteData.Values["id"].Tostring()!=null)`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that RouteData is of type IRouteData you can mock it like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestMockingConcreteClass()
    {
        MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();

        RouteData routeData = mockRepository.Stub<RouteData>();

        routeData.Stub(r => r.Values["id"]).Return("XXX");

        mockRepository.ReplayAll();

        Assert.That(routeData.Values["id"].ToString(), Is.EqualTo("XXX"));


    }
```

Comment: thanks Morten. I have used the other Approach, Which is slightly different. I will Post now.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling I got this to : 
     Declared at the Class Level

```
     HttpContextBase httpContextMock;
      ControllerBase controllerMock;

 In the Constructor
         mockRepository = new MockRepository();
         httpContextMock = mockRepository.DynamicMock<HttpContextBase>();
        controllerMock = mockRepository.DynamicMock<ControllerBase>();

      In The Test Method:
       var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("id", "Value");

      absenceController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContextMock,    routeData, controllerMock);
```

``