# MVC3 with Rhino mocks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rhino-mocks

I am trying to use Rhino mocks in my MVC3 Project. Can someone provide me links how to start up? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Here is an example of using [Rhino Mocks with MVC3.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452626/mock-routedata-in-rhinomocks-mvc3) If that's not what you're looking for, would you please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03.aspx would be a good start.